# Stability of the null solution of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I know how to do the phase portraits for linear system of equation with constant coefficeints and also to linearize the non linear systems. But  If I have to check the stability of the null solutions of the following*emphasized text* type :
$$x'(t) = -y\cos (x)$$
$$ y'(t) = \sin(x). $$
Then I am confuse to linearize it first or should I find the lyapunov function but how to find its lyapunov function. 
Any idea is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Linearization is useless here because the matrix of the linearized system 
$$\left.
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
y\sin x&-\cos x\\
\cos x&0
\end{array}\right)\right|_{(0,0)}=
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0&-1\\
1&0
\end{array}\right)
$$
has the pure imaginary eigenvalues $\pm i$.

Suppose the Lyapunov function is of the form
$$
V(x,y)=\phi(x)+\psi(y),
$$
then
$$
\dot V= -\phi'(x)  y\cos x +\psi'(y) \sin x.
$$
It is easy to observe that $\dot V$ vanishes when
$$
\phi'(x)=\tan x,\quad \psi'(y)=y,
$$
thus, $$
V(x,y)=\frac{y^2}2-\ln \cos x
$$
is a Lyapunov function of our system and also it is its first integral.

Hence, the origin is stable (but not asymptotically stable).

Comment: Do we always have to find Lyapunov function with this trial method ?

Comment: @Mathslover shah This method can be used for simple cases. There are some methods for constructing Lyapunov functions. Take a look, for insance, at this presentation: https://wolfweb.unr.edu/~fadali/EE776/LyapFuncConstruct.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately I could not open the link you have sent.

Comment: @Mathslover shah It works for me. Anyway, here is another one: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/101108047/module13/Lecture%2032.pdf (or you can google the variable gradient method and Krasovskii’s method)